# How to extract a value of a key from a long string with sed?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have a long string and from that string I want to extract a value of a key and store it in a variable. I want to extract value of `userName` from `abc` string. I tried below code but it say's file name too long error.

```
abc="Create [newSystem=System [identityDomain=bbundlesystemser201201-test, admin=AdminUser [firstName=BSystemAdminGivenName, middleName=null, lastName=BSystemAdminFalilyName, userName=bbundlesystemadminusername, password=*******, email=hello@example.com], idmConsoleURL=https://abc.com.jspx, sftpHost=d910.abc.com, sftpUser=3pyylzoo, sftpPwd=*******]]"
echo $abc
sed -n 's/^userName= //p' "$abc"
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing? I want to extract value of `userName` and store it in a variable.

```
userName=bbundlesystemadminusername
```

Comment: because `$abc` is not a filename. it is a string. You need to pass it in with a here string via `<<< "$abc"`. Your regex is also wrong.

Comment: `echo $abs | sed ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use BASH regex matching:

```
[[ $abc =~ userName=([^][,[:space:]]+) ]] && userName="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "$userName"
```

```
bbundlesystemadminusername
```

Or else, you can use this `sed` command:

```
userName=$(sed 's/.*userName=\([^][,[:space:]]*\).*/\1/' <<< "$abc")
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for all fields in the OP's input. Try it with `email` and `sftpPwd`. I've accounted for that in the regex in my answer.

Comment: I would suggest `[[ $abc =~ email=([^][,[:space:]]+) ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`

Answer (score 2):

I think I'd do this with an associative array and process substitution in bash 4:

```
$ declare -A a
$ while IFS== read k v; do a["$k"]="$v"; done < <(grep -oEi '[a-z]+=[^], ]+' <<<"$abc")
$ printf '%q\n' "${a[userName]}"
bbundlesystemadminusername
```

While this doesn't properly respect the data structure of your input variable, it does recognize key=value pairs and save them in an easily accessible array, using only a single `grep -o` to split the string into the KV pairs. The nice this about this is of course that you've got the rest of the data also available to you, should you want to avoid unnecessary calls to `grep` or `awk` or `sed` or whatever.

Note that associative arrays were added to bash in version 4. If you're doing this in macOS (or indeed in a POSIX shell), it'll have to be adjusted.